# Trying to set a link services through registerd app to azure data lake storage and keep getting 24200 error

Tags: azure

I am new to azure. We have azure data lake storage set. I am trying to set the link services from the data factory to the azure data lake storage gen2. It keeps failing when I test the link service to the data lake storage. As far as I can see, I have granted the "Storage blob contributor" role to the user in the azure data lake storage. I still keep getting permission denied error when I test the link services

```
ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: Storage operation '' on container 'testconnection' get failed with 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden''. Possible root causes: (1). It's possible because the service principal or managed identity don't have enough permission to access the data. (2). It's possible because some IP address ranges of Azure Data Factory are not allowed by your Azure Storage firewall settings. Azure Data Factory IP ranges please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses.. Account: 'dlsisrdatapoc001'. ErrorCode: 'AuthorizationFailure'. Message: 'This request is not authorized to perform this operation.'.
```

What I could observe is that when I open the network to all (public) in the data lake storage, it works, when I set the firewall with CIDR it fails. Couldn't narrow the cause of the problem. I do have the "Allow azure services on the trusted services list to access this account" checked.

Completely lost

Answer (score 0):

***As mentioned in the error description, the error usually occurs if you don't have sufficient permissions to perform the action or if you don't add the required IPs in the firewall settings of your storage account.***

To resolve the error, please check if you added the **`Storage Blob Data Contributor`** role to your **managed identity** along with the user like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Storage Accounts -> Your Storage Account -> Access Control (IAM) ->Add role assignment*

[image]

Make sure to select the managed identity, based on the **authentication method** you selected while creating linked service.

As mentioned in this [***MsDoc***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses#azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses-specific-regions), make sure to add all the required IPs based on your resource location and service tag.

***Download the JSON file to know the IP range for service tag in your resource location and add them in the firewall settings like below:***

[image]

> **Make sure to select the Resource type as
> `Microsoft.DataFactory/factories` while choosing CIDR.**

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Error when I am trying to connect between Azure Data factory and Azure Data lake Gen2 by **Anushree Garg**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69769292/error-when-i-am-trying-to-connect-between-azure-data-factory-and-azure-data-lake)

[Storage Accoung V2 access with firewall, VNET to data factory V2 by **Cindy Pau**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59632050/storage-accoung-v2-access-with-firewall-vnet-to-data-factory-v2?rq=1)